# Website entry confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a confirmation box for php site to confirm entering you are over the age of 18 exactly like this

http://www.bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/

but not sure what to do so it doesn't keep showing itself while browsing the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage.

```
<div id="hide4ever" style="display:none">text
  <button onclick="hideNow()">close</button>
</div>
<script>
  if (!localStorage.hide4ever)
     document.getElementById('hide4ever').style.display = "fixed";//or whatever

  function hideNow() {
     document.getElementById('hide4ever').style.display = "none";
    localStorage.hide4ever="true";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What call this please?

Comment: Does not do anything